# Highlight a div

Tags: jquery

When I select some text, it is copied to a textarea. But is it possible if I clic somewhere in a div, it copies all the div ? and not only the text I selected.
I have this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).bind("mouseup", function() {
        var sel = $.selection('html');
        if (sel != '') {
            $('#yourTextAreaId').val(sel);
            $('#yourDivId').html(sel);
        }
    });
});
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text1) property of jquery to get the text content of a node which you can then place into the textarea.

```
$("yourselector").click(function(){
  $("#yourTextAreaId").val($(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To select div's text try this:

```
$(document).on('click',function(event){
    var text = event.target.innerHTML;
    console.log(text);
});
```

To highlight div you can try this:

```
$(document).on('click',function(event){
    var text = event.target.style.background='yellow'; 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#yourDivId").click(function() {
  $("#yourTextAreaId").val($(this).html());
});
```